# Overcoming the logic level translator limitations

Tags: level-shifting, logic-level, level-translation

Good morning everyone,

I have a STM32F407 microcontroller running on 3.3V logic level, and I have a plethora of peripherals that I want to connect to it. The problem is that these peripherals run at anything but 3.3V level. Some of them are 1.8, some are 2.5, and a couple of 5V devices.

Immediate solution that comes to mind: programmable logic level translator. There are a lot of dual supply bi-directional level translator ICs available; I can turn these into "programmable" ones with the help of digital potentiometers.

My only problem is the common requirement of logic level translator ICs: Vcc > Vl, i.e. voltage on one side of the translator must be strictly less that voltage on the other side. But what I want is:

controller side logic level: fixed at 3.3V,

GPIO side level: anything from 1.8 to 5 V.

Are there any solutions to this problem (either through ICs or discrete elements), or am I asking too much?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use the same translator for each peripheral?

Comment: @CL ideally - yes; in short, the question is about the ability to level-shift a *single* signal line (or a pair of such) in a wide range of voltages.

Comment: Can the peripherals provide the voltage to power the level shifter? That would allow you to have the right level without any configuration.

Comment: @Botnic - I guess no, as most of 'em are sensors (I provide voltages for them via separate power rails).

Comment: @DmitriyKhudorozhkov, that doesn't make your point. If you can supply each sensor with its required voltage, you can also supply that voltage to the level translator.

Comment: @ThePhoton - this is correct, but read the post: some sensors are 5V. I can't supply 5V to the VL, because it will be > than Vcc (3.3V). What I ask is the walkaround for this particular situation.

Comment: Do you absolutely require bi-directional translation?

Comment: @ThePhoton - yes, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you supply a direction control signal, or is this for something like I2C where the direction is dynamic?

Comment: @ThePhoton - including I2C, yes.

Comment: @ThePhoton I was even thinking of using 1:2 demultiplexer (selectable by >3.3V and <3.3V conditions) with one output handling 3.3-to-1.8 shifting and another one handling 5-to-3.3. But I'm not quite sure of such a frankencirtuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is, design your system to accommodate translation from 3.3 V on the uC side to lower and equal voltages on the peripheral side.

Then if you have a 5 V peripheral, include as part of the peripheral circuit a translator to translate from 5 V on the peripheral side to 3.3 V on the uC side. This means that 5 V peripherals will have their signals running through two translator circuits.

Answer (score 1):

If your 5V peripherals are inputs to the uC, then using a device from the [74LCX series](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/search.do?query=74LCX&tabbed=Y&clearFilters=Y&searchType=others) can help. These devices are designed to have 5V tolerant inputs in a 3.3V system.

You may need to watch out for the Volp (quiet output bounce) specification. This is a measure of how much disturbance a quiet output experiences when any other output changes state.